# Is ENB mainly CPU or GPU dependent?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Because I am getting huge frame drops when using ENB 0.113 for Skyrim, I was wondering what ENB demands the most of. CPU or GPU. Can anybody answer that question?

Comment: Perhaps concentrating on "Why do I get huge frame rate drops using ENB for Skyrim?" and describing your computer environment might yield more helpful answers ... perhaps even one that might be useful to someone else down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> v0.106: Optimized code to make it less **cpu** dependent.

Patch log.

> ii. Low/Unstable Frames Per Second(consistently below 30FPS)?
>   (a) different combinations of core presets and optional effects. 
>   (b) **Disable as many active/background programs as you can**. Disable GPU
>   monitoring software, Steam Chat, etc.

Both this fragments is from their [readme](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/11318).

GPU make it possible to turn it on and CPU make it playable with solid amount of FPS.

Comment: As said, I use the 0.113 version, so it makes no difference.

Comment: @bram vanroy How does it not make a difference. Obviously enb uses both cpu and gpu. as is apparent from the patch log. however wether it uses more cpu or gpu is dependant on the settings and not the program itself

Comment: @SergeBekenkamp: since I' running 0.113 and the changelog talks of 0.106 it does not matter. The question was, what is stressed the most by using ENB, a CPU or GPU and that is not really answered. If it depends on the settings, one could elaborate on that and explain a little further.

Comment: @Bram "Less CPU dependent" in the changelog doesn't make it not still CPU dependent. The Eiffel Tower is less tall than Mount Everest—does that make the Eiffel Tower a short building? ENB of any version number is hard on the CPU.

Comment: @Bram the only way the statement `it makes no difference` would be valid is if you tested both .113 and .106 side by side and saw absolutely no difference, as mentioned by @Serge ENB is going to use both CPU and GPU, and based on the settings applied it may use one more than the other. Answering this definitively will require you to actually provide *significantly* more information as per the comment on your question.